# Loading simple Javascript in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am fairly new to components and wondered if someone could help me implement this example code found on w3 schools(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp).

It's basically a fairly simple slideshow which the user can scroll through images. The problem is I'm unable to use script tags inside components so i can't see a way of running the javascript. I've read about required tag (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation) but i can't seem to implement this. I added the code in to a javascript static resource and called it but it wont run. Below is the code i have so far. Would it be possible to just run this code in the controller as this use script correct?

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >


    <ltng:require
        scripts="{!$Resource.ScriptForCara}"

       />



<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">


    <img class="mySlides" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/949787136030539782/LnRrYf6e.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/949787136030539782/LnRrYf6e.jpg" style="width:100%"/>

  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

</div>

</aura:component>
```

```
//Script file

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty trivial to "port" to Aura. You could create those methods and call them from the controller, but it's so easy to write this in native code. Here's the Aura version:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="currentSlide" type="Integer" default="0" />
    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
        <img aura:id="image" class="mySlides" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/949787136030539782/LnRrYf6e.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
        <img aura:id="image" class="mySlides" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/949787136030539782/LnRrYf6e.jpg" style="width:100%"/>

        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="{!c.previous}">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="{!c.next}">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    previous: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.goToSlide(component, -1);
    },
    next: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.goToSlide(component, 1);
    }
})
```

---

```
({
    goToSlide: function(component, modifier) {
        // like document.getElementsByClassName, uses aura:id
        var images = component.find("images");
        // Optimized wrapping method
        var slide = Math.mod(images.length + component.get("v.currentSlide") + modifier, images.length);
        component.set("v.currentSlide", slide);
        // Hide all images, slds-hide is built-in to SLDS.
        images.forEach(function(image) {
            $A.utils.addClass(image, 'slds-hide');
        });
        // Show the one that's current
        $A.utils.removeClass(images[slide], 'slds-hide');
    }
})
```

With some modification, you could load the URLs dynamically, show the current slide via a dot or other UI, and so on. For trivial scripts, it's almost always worth it to just re-write from scratch.

---

But, as an exercise in "how you'd make this work as a learning exercise", here's what you'd do.

## Step 1: Convert inline JS to controller calls

```
<button data-dir="-1" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="{!c.nav}">&#10094;</button>
<button data-dir="1" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="{!c.nav}">&#10095;</button>
```

## Step 2: Write a controller

```
({
    nav: function(c, e, h) {
       plusDivs(parseInt(e.target.getElement().dataset.dir))
    }
})
```

Note that the controller methods will fail until the script loads, but this should be nigh instantaneous, so users are unlikely to be able to click the button before the script is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I will try this out and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate**

You can use `lighting:Carousel` for image slider, it's salesforce inbuild lighting component, Please go through the [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:carousel/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleCarousel)